# Mapear View - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sei que já foi perguntado algo parecido, mas nas respostas que achei falou que para mapear a view deveria colocar o DataAnnotation [Table("nome view")] ou configurar na Fluent API

Criei uma view no banco de dados chamada "Users". Então criei uma classe chamada UserView

```
[Table("Users")]
public class UserView 
{
  public string EmailAddress { get; set;} 
  ......
}
```

Depois no meu DbContext criei o DbSet

```
public DbSet<UserView> Users { get; set; }
```

Quando eu rodei a aplicação tive um erro do tipo "The model backing the context has changed since the database was created."

Então no Nuget Package Console eu entrei com

> Update-Database -force -verbose

Então tive um erro que **já existe um objeto chamado "Users"**. Lá no console até mostrou um "CREATE TABLE USERS ...." ou seja, ele tentou criar a tabela.

Estou usando Automatic Migrations. Como eu poderia mapear essa view já existente e/ou criar ela se não existir?

Comment: Criou uma `view` no banco de dados?

Comment: Sim. Criei a view direto no Management Studio

Comment: Ahhh bom, pensei que você tava confundindo view com model (MVC).

Comment: Você sabe que o EF vai tentar criar uma tabela no banco e não uma view, certo?

Comment: Eu percebi sim. Vi no package console a instrução pra criar a tabela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto está **totalmente errado**. Se você tem um contexto gerenciado pelo Entity Framework, não pode mapear objetos somente leitura nele.

Crie um segundo contexto somente leitura, assim:

```
public class ReadOnlyContext: DbContext
{
    public ReadOnlyContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ReadOnlyContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Coloque nele o `DbSet` que lerá a *view* de banco:

```
public class ReadOnlyContext: DbContext
{
    public ReadOnlyContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ReadOnlyContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<UserView> UsersView { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: obrigado @cigano criando um contexto novo deu certo

Comment: E se eu tenho classes relacionadas a este contexto? no meu caso por exemplo tenho uma classe chamada usuário que é gerida por outra aplicação, ou seja nesta minha app, não posso fazer Inserts/Updates/Delete, mas preciso guardar o usuário relacionado, como tratar, visto que estão em contextos separados?

Comment: @AlexBecker Não será um relacionamento tratado pelo Entity Framework. Uma forma de resolver seria criar uma View de Banco no banco de dados em que o contexto do EF está mapeado.