# Trabalhando com view em um contexto no Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Fala Pessoal Tudo certo!? 
Estou com um certo problema que gostaria que me ajudassem.

Bom tenho uma aplicação simples com 4 tabelas relacionadas

[image: Classes]

Estou utilizando o entity framework 6, meu problema é na classe USUARIOS, pois na realidade ela é uma VIEW, de outro banco de dados, pesquisando sobre isso vi que posso criar outro contexto(readonly) [Mapear View - Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132088/mapear-view-entity-framework)  para consultar esta view, mas meu problema é que em outras classes preciso ter o relacionamento com a tabela de usuários, como posso fazer isso?
Quando incluo ela no meu contexto principal o sistema tentar criar a tabela usuários mas da um erro pois ja existe a view no banco de dados.

Abaixo um trecho do meu código:

```
    public class BancoContexto: DbContext
{
    public BancoContexto(): base("conexao")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

    }
    public DbSet<LinhaProducao> LinhaProducao { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AreaResponsavel> AreaResponsavel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cartao> Cartao { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<USUARIOS> USUARIOS { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AreaResponsavel>().ToTable("AreaResponsavel");
        modelBuilder.Entity<LinhaProducao>().ToTable("LinhaProducao");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cartao>().ToTable("Cartao");

        //aqui é o meu problema
        modelBuilder.Entity<USUARIOS>().ToTable("USUARIOS");



        #endregion

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class AreaResponsavel
{
    [Key]
    public int AreaResponsavelID { get; set; }
    public string NomeArea { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public virtual USUARIOS Responsavel { get; set; }
}
public class Cartao
{
    public int CartaoID { get; set; }
    public int NroCartao { get; set; }
    public int OrdemProducao { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPeca { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoProblema { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataHoraInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataHoraFim { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public USUARIOS Colaborador { get; set; }
    public int LinhaProducaoID { get; set; }
    public LinhaProducao Linha { get; set; }
    public int MaquinasAfetadas { get; set; }
    public int AreaResponsavelID { get; set; }
    public AreaResponsavel Area { get; set; }
    public int LiderID { get; set; }
    public USUARIOS Lider { get; set; }
    public bool Gemba { get; set; }
}
public class LinhaProducao
{
    public int LinhaProducaoID { get; set; }
    public string NomeLinha { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public USUARIOS Responsavel { get; set; }
}
```

Veja que nas classes acima tenho o relacionamento com a classe Usuário!!!

Desde ja agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode desativar a alteração automática da database, com o código a seguir no construtor da sua classe de contexto:

Database.SetInitializer(null);

Desse jeito, ele não vai mais tentar criar a tabela, mas daí vc vai ter que aplicar manualmente as alterações.

Eu consideraria utilizar migrations, dessa forma vc determina quando as alterações no banco serão geradas, o migrations pode inclusive gerar os scripts prontos para você, te dando a chance de aplicar vc mesmo os scripts, sem correr risco de a ferramenta fazer alguma barbeiragem no seu banco, daí você evita a criação da tabela que na verdade é uma view.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Fernando! Bom na realidade estou utilizando Code First, mas gostaria de evitar fazer manualmente os scripts, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma  de fazer com que o sistema reconheça aquela entidade como uma view no banco e não como uma tabela...

Comment: Ah desculpa, achei que era model-first devido as imagens do diagrama de classes.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta, na verdade acredito que não tem como fazer o que você quer, dei uma pesquisada, uso views aqui, mas não com geração automática das tabelas. Como disse alí o migrations gera tudo pra vc, inclusive, aplica as alterações, a diferença é que vc tem que rodar um comando no vs pedindo para gerar as alterações do contexto em determinada base.